# c++, 'avg = sum/5' gives me junk values but writing avg = sum/2 gives works and i don't know why

Tags: c++, sum, average

I'm trying to create a simple program with c++. that calculates the average of 5 numbers that the user inputs but it keeps giving me a junk value when i run it. I've spent over 30 minutes messing with this trying to fix it but i can't seem to figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>  

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello this my program" << '\n';
    int sum, avg;

    int numbOne{  }, numbTwo{  }, numbThree{  }, numbFour{  }, numbFive{  };
    std::cout << "enter your first number: ";
    std::cin >> numbOne;

    std::cout << "enter your second number: ";
    std::cin >> numbTwo;

    std::cout << "enter your third number: ";
    std::cin >> numbThree;

    std::cout << "enter your fourth number: ";
    std::cin >> numbFour;

    std::cout << "enter your fifth number:";
    std::cin >> numbFive;

    sum = numbOne+numbTwo+numbThree+numbFour+numbFive;

    avg = sum/5;

    std::cout << "the average is: " << avg << '\n;';
}
```

this is what gets printed in console.

```
hello this my program
enter your first number: 1
enter your second number: 2
enter your third number: 3
enter your fourth number: 4
enter your fifth number:5
the average is: 32619
```

Comment: Have you debugged what the values of `numbOne` etc are?  (e.g. put a `std::cout` above your `sum =` to get the values)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is why: `'\n;'`
I'm sure you meant to put double quotes.. Or a if you use single, `'\n'` followed by `';'`..

So it should be: `"\n";` or `'\n';`

As pointed out in the comments, you should enable your compiler warnings like `-Wall` and `-Wextra`. They will help you see the problem `-Wmultichar`

Comment: If you compile with warnings you will see a message about it (`g++ -Wall -Wextra` ...): as shown here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/eFFFIHmcv8rXVdQp *warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]*

Comment: @RyanHaining; Thanks for that. For the life of me, I couldn't remember what this was called. `-Wmultichar` fixed my brain after seeing it lol.

Comment: Good eye spotting that!

Comment: Nice. Should also be mentioned that one more correction is needed: in order to properly compute an average, `avg` must be declared as float (or double) instead of int (for `sum`, a cast to float/double is enough). For example, the instance (11+12+13+14+15)/5 should yield 12,8 but the OP's code will output 13.

Comment: @RonaldSouza, The average of `11, 12, 13, 14 and 15` *is* `13`

Comment: @SidS Oops, thx!! :) My point holds anyway: consider the instance `(1+2+3+4+7)/5`. The above code yields `3`, when it should be `3.4`.